# What is the max of maximum_execution_time in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have about **200,000** rows that need to add to the database.

I have set my `maximum_excution_time = 4000`, I still get this error.

[image]

What is max of maximum_execution_time in PHP ?

I want to take off this restriction completely and set it to unlimited if possible.

Comment: If you set it to 0 there is no limit

Comment: some hosting providers prohibit you from overriding ini directives

Comment: run the script from the command line (no limit) no one is having fun watching a browser for 4000 seconds

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar pagination is for display, noting to do with inserting in to the db

Comment: @Dagon : Since you have 2 up-votes on your comments, do you mind provide more details or put together an answer for this post ? as a matter of fact, I use CLI to execute my PHP script, and at the end of my script, I generate a **result/report** as an HTML page, and that's how I get my screenshot.

Comment: then is it the report generation at fault? I don't use laravel so i can only speak in broad terms

Comment: @Fred-ii- im 12bit 4,096

Comment: @Fred-ii- its the bandwidth that counts

Comment: Thanks guys for ruining my comments section. :(

Comment: @Dagon Aaahhhh ok. Let's get rid of these *fun* comments.

Comment: To add to @Dagon's comment, if you need to do this periodically (it sounds like it...) you can do it from a cron-job and send yourself an e-mail when it's done. Then you wouldn't need your html page any more.

Comment: its not *your* comment section, we were here first ;)

Comment: @Dagon : Good one ;)

Comment: Your script should have no issue inserting that many records in this amount of time.  Add some benchmarking to see which parts of the script are taking the longest to figure out where you need to optimize.

Comment: What do you mean by add some **benchmarking** ? Can you provide a little more details please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know using a value of `0` in `set_time_limit` will tell PHP to not timeout a script/program before it's finished running. I'm pretty sure setting the same value in `maximum_excution_time` will have the same effect.

That said: Some hosting companies have other systems running to look for long running processes of any sort (PHP, Ruby, Perl, random programs, etc.) and kill them if they're running too long.  There's nothing you can do to stop these system from killing your process (other than moving to a different host)

Also, certain versions of PHP have a number of small memory leaks/inefficient garbage collection that can start to eat up memory when using in long running processes.  You may hit PHP memory limit with this, or you may eat up the amount of memory available to your virtual machine.

If you run into these challenges, the usual approach is to batch process the rows in some way.

Hope that helps, and good luck!

**Update**: Re batch processing -- if you find you're stuck on a system that can only insert around 10,000 rows at a time, rather than write a program to insert all 200,000 rows at once, you write a program/system that will insert, say, 9,000 and then stop.  And then you run it again and it inserts the next 9,000.  And then next 9,000 until you're complete.  How you do this will depend on where you're getting your data from.  If you're pulling this data from flat files it can be as simple as splitting the flat files into multiple files.  If your'e pulling from another database table it can be as simple as writing a program to pull out arrays of IDs in groups of 9,000 and have your main program select those 9,000 rows.  Messaging queue systems are another popular approach for this sort of task.

Comment: I got everything you said, thank you so much for that, but what do you mean by `batch process the rows` ? I hope you dont mind clarify it a little bit more.

Comment: @iori Updated the post with more context, hope that helps.

Comment: Precisely, I will take this advice, thank you so much. You're awesome @Alan :D